# Add single line to chartjs.org on Y-axis point

Tags: chart.js

Keep in mind I am no JavaScript expert by any stretch, so some CliffsNotes on how this works would be helpful.

I have a simple line chart built in chartjs.org:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("sample-chart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(document.getElementById("sample-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['3/4', '3/5', '3/6', '3/7', '3/8', '3/9', '3/10', '3/11', '3/21', '3/22', '3/23', '3/24', '3/25', '3/26'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Execution Time',
        data: [20, 21.8, 32.8, 43, 25.3, 25.7, 26.0, 24.7, 26, 45.8, 24.3, 21.2, 18.5, 25.4]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: false
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }
});
```

On the date represented in the chart of 3/8, an event happened. I want to draw a red line on that date on the vertical marker that has a hover label with some very basic, non-HTML text.

I made a Codepen here (I couldn't get 4.x working, so I used 3.5 on the pen):
https://codepen.io/eln00b/pen/ZEqaJvQ

I've been trying to RTFM but not been having luck. As usual, I think I'm asking the wrong questions to figure out what is going on. I think I want to look at [Ticks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration), but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: You could use `chartjs-plugin-annotation`. The following sample could serve as a starter: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/samples/line/visibility.html.

Comment: @uminder I wasn't aware that existed. I will try that. I was too focused on "stuff built in" and didn't look into the plugins. I will dig into that and see if anyone comes up with anything else while I do that. Greatly appreciated for such a useful pointer here.

Comment: I think I need to track down a typo or something in the codepen at this point.

Comment: Sometimes, depending on what you need to do with it, a line can be  just a `line`, that is a new dataset with the ends of that segment as coordinates. Making it start from an axis that is not placed at a preset position will need adjusting that end of the segment after the axis limits were computed, using one of that axis [callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks). See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tzg49nb/) for an example.